# .htaccess forward from one domain to a specific .html page

Tags: .htaccess

I know how to use `.htaccess` to forward everything in one domain to a new domain name. But in this case, I want everything from one domain to go to a specific `.html` page on a different domain. That's where I'm lost. I'm trying the following but it just redirects to a folder and the page in question is in that folder but obviously, I don't want people seeing the contents of that folder. Make any sense? So `example.com` needs to go to `yyy.com/some-page.html`

This is what I'm currently using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?5\.xxxx\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.1.yyy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

So how about just a simple redirect?

Try this in your `.htaccess` file.

```
redirect 301 / http://somesite.com/somepage.html
```

OR you can try this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somesite.com/somepage.html [R=301,L]
```

It does work and you can test my RewriteRule below.

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

There must be something else going on.

Comment: Where exactly is the .htaccess located on the OLD domain? I know that works as well as the updated answer. There is something else going on with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?5\.xxxx\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.1.yyy.com/some-page.html [R,L]
```

You can also put a blank index.html page to the directory in question to mask its contents or
you can put index.php file with this code `<? header ("location: http://www.1.yyy.com/some-page.html"); ?>` that will redirect a user to the desired page.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the RewriteEngine examples worked. They all did the same thing and that was to go to a folder and not the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

$1 is a place holder for the 1st pattern match.  So if you are rewriting domaina.com/someurl/, it is attempting to load domainb.com/someurl/.  Swap the $1 with the actual page --- e.g. somepage.html and it should work.  But unless both of these domains are pointing to the same files/directories, the rule seems a bit overcomplicated.